# Serializing an object with OneToOneField

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to send my Scenes object with the context dictionary over to a template. These are the models:

```
class Scene1(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Scene2(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Scenes(models.Model):
    scene1 = models.OneToOneField(Scene1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scene2 = models.OneToOneField(Scene2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I do

```
queryset = Scenes.objects.filter(id=1).values()
context = {"scenes": queryset[0]}
print(queryset)
```

I get:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'scene1_id': 3, 'scene2_id': 3,}]>
```

How would I serialize the data to make all the information in Scene1 and Scene2 visible in the context dictionary?

Comment: Try to use Django rest framework. It provides powerful serialization tools out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add to_dict method at Model. For example;

```
class Scene1(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def to_dict():
        return {'timestamp': self.timestamp.isoformat(), 'number': self.number,'name': self.name}

class Scene2(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def to_dict():
        return {'timestamp': self.timestamp.isoformat(), 'number': self.number,'name': self.name}

class Scenes(models.Model):
    scene1 = models.OneToOneField(Scene1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scene2 = models.OneToOneField(Scene2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def to_dict():
        return {'scene1': self.scene1.to_dict(), 'scene2': self.scene2.to_dict()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using these serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class Scene1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scene1
        fields = ('name',)

class Scene2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scene2
        fields = ('name',)


class ScenesDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    scene1 = Scene1Serializer()
    scene2 = Scene2Serializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Scenes
        fields = ('scene1', 'scene2')
```

then in my view:

```
queryset = Scenes.objects.filter(id=1)
scenes = queryset[0]
scenes_serialized = ScenesDetailSerializer(scenes)
data = scenes_serialized.data
print(data) # prints: {'scene1': OrderedDict([('name', some_name_1)]), 'scene2': OrderedDict([('name', some_name_2)])

context = {"scenes": data}
```

now in the template I can use dot notation to get the name variable:

```
{{ scenes.scene1.name }}
{{ scenes.scene2.name }}
```